Record Inserted But Is Not Found In The Next Loop
so i am doing a manual "Get Receipt Line". The code below is run inside a PurchRcptLn loop (after some validations, run the code below)
 GetReceipts.SetPurchHeader(PurchInvHead);
 GetReceipts.CreateInvLines(PurchRcptLn);

where
  GetReceipts: Codeunit "Purch.-Get Receipt";
  PurchRcptLn: Record "Purch. Rcpt. Line";
  PurchInvHead: Record "Purchase Header";

somehow it inserts a line of purchase line on the first loop, for the first receipt line record, but it is not known to the second loop so it tried to insert  the second receipt line with line no. 10000.
What is happening? Is this related to database locking? Any solution?
Thank you.
